# Where does the sudo .bashrc file reside?

Tags: macos

Where doe the sudo .bashrc file reside? I'd like to add some things to it.

Comment: There isn't a "sudo  .bashrc". `sudo` uses the callers environment modified as prescribed in `/private/etc/sudoers`. What is your goal?

Comment: @fd0 I have an alias in my normal .bashrc, however when running sudo it doesn't pick it up.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use `sudo --set-home` and/or `sudo --login` when I care about the dot files so that the environment gets set up more like the normal user than the restricted environment.

This seems a bit like an XY problem though, it really depends on what you are trying to do if setting up a proper root user with a proper environment is needed or if you can modify the sudo behavior using standard flags and functionality.

You can find the home folders generally with this set of commands:

```
sudo -s
who am i
whoami
pwd
```

In the first case, you are the normal user with root - sticking to the old user home folder and dot files. If you instead do `sudo --login` you'll see the home folder for root. By default it is `/var/root`

Answer (score -1):

*.bashrc* is usually in `/Users/your_username/`

To access this path, open Terminal :

`$ open ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I know where my .bashrc file is. I'm wondering where ´sudo´ a.k.a. roots .bashrc file is.

Answer (score -1):

see `man bash` under `FILES`

```
/bin/bash
         The bash executable
/etc/profile
         The systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells
~/.bash_profile
         The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
~/.bashrc
         The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
~/.bash_logout
         The  individual  login shell cleanup file, executed when a login
              shell exits
~/.inputrc
         Individual readline initialization file
```

Comment: Which of these files are read in the situation described in the question?